# How to do two tasks at the same time in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to do two tasks together

I tried `import mulitprocessing`

`multiprocessing.Process(target=print('hi') , args=(i,) , target=print('hello'),args=('hello')`

But it did not work.

Any solutions?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/. If you [edit] your question I'd be happy to remove the downvote.

Comment: To understand why the problem you are describing is more complicated than you might think, have a look at this talk of Raymond Hettiger about Concurrency (https://youtu.be/Bv25Dwe84g0)

Answer (score -1):

An example of how this can be achieved using the multiprocessing module from the standard library:

```py
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    
    p = Pool(numberOfProcessing)
    
    p.map(functionName, listOfArgument)
```